# Adding a node to D3 SVG from textbox

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to extend the example ['Add and remove nodes'](http://bl.ocks.org/tgk/6068367).

I want to add the `node name` entered in the `text box` to the `SVG`. Clicking the `Add N` button calls `addNode` method which takes the text value entered in the `textbox` and calls the `addNodeCanvas` (which is similar to the `mousedownCanvas` of the example).

However the `addNode` is not calling the method `addNodeCanvas`.

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 500;

var fill = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height])
  .nodes([{}]) // initialize with a single node
  .linkDistance(30)
  .charge(-60)
  .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mousemove", mousemove)
  .on("mousedown", mousedownCanvas);

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var nodes = force.nodes(),
  links = force.links(),
  node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
  link = svg.selectAll(".link");

var cursor = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 30)
  .attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)")
  .attr("class", "cursor");

restart();

function mousemove() {
  cursor.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.mouse(this) + ")");
}


function addNodeCanvas(nodeName) {
  alert(nodeName);
  var point = d3.mouse(this),
    node = {
      x: point[0],
      y: point[1],
      id: nodeName
    },
    n = nodes.push(node);

  // add links to any nearby nodes
  nodes.forEach(function(target) {
    var x = target.x - node.x,
      y = target.y - node.y;
    if (Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) < 30) {
      links.push({
        source: node,
        target: target
      });
    }
  });

  restart();
}

function mousedownCanvas() {
  var point = d3.mouse(this),
    node = {
      x: point[0],
      y: point[1]
    },
    n = nodes.push(node);

  // add links to any nearby nodes
  nodes.forEach(function(target) {
    var x = target.x - node.x,
      y = target.y - node.y;
    if (Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) < 30) {
      links.push({
        source: node,
        target: target
      });
    }
  });

  restart();
}

function mousedownNode(d, i) {
  nodes.splice(i, 1);
  links = links.filter(function(l) {
    return l.source !== d && l.target !== d;
  });
  d3.event.stopPropagation();

  restart();
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
}

function restart() {
  node = node.data(nodes);

  node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .on("mousedown", mousedownNode);

  node.exit()
    .remove();

  link = link.data(links);

  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
    .attr("class", "link");
  link.exit()
    .remove();

  force.start();
}
```

```css
#nodeConsole {
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  margin-top: 1px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#linkedNodes {
  width: 80%;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 10px;
}

#srcNodes {
  width: 40%;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 10px;
}

#targetNodes {
  width: 40%;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 10px;
}

rect {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.node {
  fill: #000;
}

.cursor {
  fill: none;
  stroke: brown;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="addNodeInput" placeholder="Node Name"></textarea>
<button id="addNode" onclick="addNode();">Add N</button>
<button id="deleteNode" onclick="deleteNode();">Del N</button>
<button id="addLink" onclick="addLink();">Add L</button>
<button id="deleteLink" onclick="deleteLink();">Del L</button>
<div id="nodeConsole"></div>
<select id="linkedNodes" size="4"> </select>

<select id="srcNodes" size="8"> </select>
<select id="targetNodes" size="8"> </select>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var cmd = "";
  var inNode = document.getElementById("addNodeInput");
  var out = document.getElementById("nodeConsole");

  function display() {
    out.value = "Node Operations";
    out.innerHTML = cmd + out.innerHTML;
    cmd = "";
  }

  function deleteNode() {
    var x = document.getElementById("srcNodes");
    var y = document.getElementById("targetNodes");
    if (x.length > 0) {
      var sel = x.selectedIndex;
      x.remove(sel);
      y.remove(sel);
    }
  }

  function addLink() {
    var x = document.getElementById("srcNodes");
    var y = document.getElementById("targetNodes");
    var link = document.createElement("option");
    var l = document.getElementById("linkedNodes");
    link.text = x.value + "<->" + y.value;
    l.add(link);
  }

  function deleteLink() {
    var x = document.getElementById("linkedNodes");
    if (x.length > 0) {
      x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
    }
  }

  function addNode() {
    var n = inNode.value;
    //cmd = ">>>" + n + "<br />";  //display(cmd);
    inNode.value = "";
    inNode.focus();
    var s = document.getElementById("srcNodes");
    var t = document.getElementById("targetNodes");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
    option2.text = n;
    t.add(option2);
    option.text = n;
    s.add(option);
    addNodeCanvas(n);


  }
</script>
```

Comment: It's because you're still trying to use 'd3.mouse(this)' to get the position for where you're going to place the node, which is null since there's no mouse event to get the position on. Maybe you could try getting the centroid of the circle that follows the mouse? Or just set it so that it still adds nodes based on click but also checks if there's anything in the node name box? Or just give it a default position?

Comment: it is even not showing an alert `alert(nodeName);` which is the first statement in the function `addNodeCanvas(nodeName)`

Comment: I'm getting an alert when I uploaded it to codepen? I deleted the alert you had in the addNode() function and kept in the one in the addNodeCanvas() function and it still alerted? Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBopWx?editors=1011, it just won't do anything after that because you're trying to use d3.mouse(this) when there is no mouse event to call.

Comment: thanks, I'll use codepen; I was using jsfiddle earlier; since I am getting an alert now, I'll now start tweaking the d3.mouse code.